Laravel Page Expired Safari
The title is pretty self explanatory,
When posting my login form using Safari 100% of the times it returns a 419 | Page Expired.
I'm using Laravel Breeze to handle Auth, I believe it has nothing to do with the error because it works perfectly when using Arc, Edge, Chrome and Brave. (Not tested in other browsers)
Is there anything I'm missing?

have any extension being used in safari?

You have something in safari blocking cookies for this site, or generally. Monitor cookies and ensure a laravel session cookie is created when you load the login page.

It's vanilla safari, no ext installed. The laravel session cookie is being created.
